# Using jquery.on with 2 different instances of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have element selector and i want to use jquery. But i dont want to break jquery instance that already exist in page. So i rename jQuery to anotherJquery for my instance and all works fine until i use

`anotherJquery ("body *:not(.sg_ignore)").on("click", { 'self': this }, this.sgMousedown);`

After this all clicks events go to my instance of jquery even after:

```
anotherJquery ("body *").off("click", { 'self': this }, this.sgMousedown);
```

How to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Do you need two version due to a plugin?  How are you going to `break` the jquery instance?

Comment: I need two versions because of i test code for one version and page may contain other version.

Comment: As for "break" function in jquery may be deprecated or change behaviour. So i can't change page version of jquery.

Comment: You should be testing using the same version

Comment: I want to inject selector on any page.

Answer (score 0):

from jquery manual

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict(true) from the second version will
>   return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.

try using `$.noConflict(true)`

Comment: i try but it did not help.